# Prevent user from typing numbers anywhere in input. How to?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an input from user

I want to prevent user from typing numbers anywhere in input.

Currently stuck at this:

```js
let name = prompt('Enter your name:');

function isNumber(str) {
        let replaced = str.replace(/\D/g, ""); //deleting all symbols from a String
        return parseInt(replaced); //parsing string numbers to actual numbers -> returning
}

while (typeof isNumber(name) === 'number') {
        name = prompt("You can't put NUMBERS in name input! try again: ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler - so much simpler than trying to remove all NON digits to see if there are numbers left

```js
let name = prompt('Enter your name:');

while (name.replace(/\d/g,"") !== name) {
  name = prompt("You can't put NUMBERS in name input! try again: ");
}
```

Alternatively .match or .test using a digit regexp

Comment: I’m just testing that what the user enters is the same without digits `!==` means not strictly equal